# C code working in Linux but not in MacOS Mojave

Tags: c, macos, gcc

The code that I'm trying to run is working flawlessly in linux but unfortunately it's not working on macOS.

For the same code below, when I try to run on macOS Mojave with a gcc compiler I'm getting a `Segmentation Fault: 11`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main() {
  FILE *fa;
  FILE *fb;
  int ca, cb;

  char buf[1000];
  fa = fopen("q4in.c", "r");
  if (fa == NULL) {
    printf("Cannot open file");
    exit(0);
  }
  fb = fopen("q4out.c", "w");
  ca = getc(fa);
  while (ca != EOF) {
    int i = 0;
    while (ca != '\n') {
      buf[i++] = ca;
      ca = getc(fa);
      buf[i] = '\0';
    }
    ca = getc(fa);
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    printf("%c",buf[i]);
  }
}
```

Comment: What happens if a line is longer than 999 characters? What happens if `ca == EOF` in the *inner* loop? Why the nested loops at all? And have you tried to use a debugger to catch the crash and see where in your code it happens?

Comment: You should try to use `gdb` in order to see which line is the problematic one in MacOS.

Comment: Also, I think MacOS uses `\r` as line delimiter, not `\n`.

Comment: @Some programmer dude ca==EOF prints last character

Comment: It seems as if this question fits the name of this website quite well ;-) But serious: if you have a newer GCC you can try `-fstack-protector-all` before you start to step through with GDB. It will at least  tell you if it is a stack overflow and not something else.

Comment: If the last line doesn't end with a newline `'\n'`, then `getc` will return `EOF`, which isn't equal to `'\n'`. So your inner loop will be infinite if that happen, and you will very quickly go out of bounds of your array `buf` and you will have [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: @JanneTuukkanen That was old MacOS (up to and including version 9). Since OSX (and now renamed to macOS) it's the Unix line-ending `'\n'`.

Comment: Doesn't segfault for me on MacOS. Just outputs garbage.

Comment: @CInder Biscuits I am using MacOS Mojave 10.0

Comment: @abhimanyubahree Mojave is 10.14

Comment: OT:  regarding: `printf("Cannot open file");`  1) error messages should be output to `stderr`, not `stdout`.  2) when the error indication is from a C library function, should also output the text reason the system thinks the error occurred.  The function: `perror()`  handles this correctly.  Suggest: `perror("Cannot open file");`

Comment: strongly suggest condensing the two `while()` loops to a single loop similar to: `while( ca != EOF )  if (ca != '\n' ) ...`

Comment: in the posted code, the array `buf[]` is being overlayed (and not printed) with each newline found in the file.  One of the results is the call to `printf()` only outputs the last line that was input

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to take a wild guess, and offer as an alternative that the MacOs vs Linux is a red herring.

And that the real problem is that the last line of the input file on the Mac 
 doesn't terminate with \n.

Comment: Just noticed that this solution was already mentioned in the comments. I can remove this, if the original commenter wants to offer it as an answer.